# Need apache2 to return 418 for all Requests

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

I need Apache2 to return a `418` response for all requests. It's on Debian8 Apache2.2.2.

When I change my `000-default.conf` I get:

```
RewriteEngine maybe mispelled on line 13
```

like this

Here are lines 13-14:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ [L,R=418]
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the correct syntax:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

`RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]`

Anyway:

`RewriteRule: invalid HTTP response code '418' for flag 'R'`

no you can't (without recompile apache)

Comment: https://www.google.com/teapot I Just want it like this.

Comment: seems like node.js does : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018008/is-there-a-server-that-implements-http-status-code-418